# Linear functionals and integration verification

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, polynomials, vector-spaces, proof-verification

[image]

Can you please verify my reasoning?

(a) Yes as [image]

(b) No, as function is squared

(c) Yes, same reasoning as (a), squared values of x do not affect linearity.

Does the region of integration affect anything?

Comment: Are you sure about $c)?$ Please, check it again.

Comment: @mfl I'm unsure why it is not a linear functional, can you please expain?

Answer (score 1):

For (b), maybe you should give an explicit counterexample: E.g. Let $f(x) = g(x) = x$.

Comment: Thanks @arithmetic, otherwise am I correct?

Comment: Yes, and also the region of integration doesn't affect the argument.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I have said for (b): $\int_0^2 (af(x)+bg(x))^2 dx$ is not equal to $a^2\int_0^2 f(x)^2 dx + b^2\int_0^2 g(x)^2 dx$ Does this work?

Comment: It does as long as $\int_0^2 f(x)g(x)$ is non zero - This can happen in some cases: E.g., $f = x-1, g = (x-1)^2$. To be safe just pick a concrete pair $f, g$.